# Fill out fixed hour-categories in MsSql-Statement

Tags: sql-server, group-by, case

I am trying to build an SQL statement which should provide data for a statistic function.

My SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(Ac_Id) As TotalCount, DATEPART(hour, Ac_Date) as HoursName, Ac_Customer_Id 
  FROM Access
 GROUP BY Ac_Customer_Id ,DATEPART(hour, Ac_Date)
 ORDER BY Ac_Customer_Id, HoursName
```

The Result looks like this:

```
TotalCount |HoursName |Customer_Id
-----------|----------|-----------
1          |6         |12345
4          |7         |12345
28         |8         |12345
40         |9         |12345
10         |10        |12345
6          |11        |12345
1          |13        |12345
4          |14        |12345
1          |15        |12345
1          |16        |12345
2          |17        |12345
1          |18        |12345
1          |19        |12345
5          |20        |12345
8          |21        |12345
7          |22        |12345
9          |23        |12345
2          |9         |65432
3          |10        |65432
4          |11        |65432
```

Now I need one Record for every single Hour of the day, The Result should therefore look like this:

```
TotalCount |HoursName |Customer_Id
-----------|----------|-----------
 0         |1         |12345
 0         |2         |12345
 0         |3         |12345
 0         |4         |12345
 0         |5         |12345
 1         |6         |12345
 4         |7         |12345
 28        |8         |12345
 40        |9         |12345
 10        |10        |12345
 6         |11        |12345
 0         |12        |12345
 1         |13        |12345
 4         |14        |12345
 1         |15        |12345
 1         |16        |12345
 2         |17        |12345
 1         |18        |12345
 1         |19        |12345
 5         |20        |12345
 8         |21        |12345
 7         |22        |12345
 9         |23        |12345
 0         |0         |65432
 0         |1         |65432
 0         |2         |65432
 0         |3         |65432
 0         |4         |65432
 0         |5         |65432
 0         |6         |65432
 0         |7         |65432
 0         |8         |65432
 2         |9         |65432
 3         |10        |65432
 4         |11        |65432
```

Computing the answers I realized, that I was unclear: I need the hours filled in for every AC_Customer_Id. I updated the Result excpectation. The problem with the answers from @Michał Turczyn and @Salman A is, that they don´t select the Ac_Customer_Id. And the

```
 0         |12        |12345
```

doesn´t show up. 
 Is it possible to do this at all?

Thank you again

Comment: Have a table (or table construct) with rows containing the values 0-23 and the `LEFT JOIN` to your dataset.

Comment: Without a tally table, you could inline the values using a derived table and row constructor: `FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),...(24)) AS hours(hour)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `CROSS JOIN` to generate all possible combinations of hourlist and customerlist:

```sql
SELECT hourlist.HoursName, customerlist.Customer_Id, COALESCE(t.TotalCount, 0)
FROM (VALUES
    (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23)
) AS hourlist(HoursName)
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id
    FROM t
) AS customerlist
LEFT JOIN t ON hourlist.HoursName = t.HoursName AND customerlist.Customer_Id = t.Customer_Id
```

It should be easy to adapt the query to match your needs.

Comment: That looks very good to me. I am just having minor Syntax Issues, But I will get back here and report. Thanks a lot

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: This solution works pretty well for me. thanks a lot!

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using "calendar" like CTE:

```
with calendarCte as (
    select 0 as [hour]
    union all
    select [hour] + 1 from calendarCte
    where [hour] < 24
)

select coalesce(a.TotalCount, 0),
       calendarCte.[hour],
       Ac_Customer_Id
from (
    SELECT COUNT(Ac_Id) As TotalCount, DATEPART(hour, Ac_Date) as HoursName, Ac_Customer_Id 
      FROM Access
     GROUP BY Ac_Customer_Id ,DATEPART(hour, Ac_Date)
) a full join calendarCte on a.HoursName = calendarCte.[hour]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question as I didn´t point out well, what I need

Comment: @hoglimo I guess my answer is still valid :)